# Java 8 functional interfaces naming convention?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, naming-conventions

Does such convention exist?
 
For example, I have a predicate: `Predicate<Integer> predicate = i -> (i < 1);` or `BiFunction<String, String, String> function = (x, y) -> x + y;`. How should I name it so the variable's type and sense would be clear?

Comment: Are you referring to naming variables of functional interface types?

Comment: No specific naming convention exists for functional interface object reference that you are asking for. You can name the object reference using the basic java naming convention.

Comment: I am not aware of any special naming convention for variables holding lambdas/method references. Usually we don't need them, we just use lambdas/method references where they are needed (which also allows them to match/use generic types of methods which are using them without us needing to specify them). But If you really must store them in variables and you want to name them, use names which make sense like "isSmallerThanOne" or "concatenate".

Comment: Personally I go for *what* it actually does: `Predicate<Integer> smallerThanOne = i < 1`

Comment: There's an old naming convention, left over from Smalltalk I think, that says method names should begin with a verb.  E.g. `setSize()` or `getWidth()`.  Maybe something like that could work?  `Predicate<Integer> testLessThanOne = i < 1`

Comment: @markspace, looks like it's actually what I'm looking for. Does it exists not only for predicates?

Comment: The point of lambdas is to reduce code. There is rarely any point creating variable declarations longer than the lambda itself (unless you are caching a capturing lambda).  You may as well inline them and not use any variable.

Comment: A lambda is an instance of a functional interface, i.e. it is a java object, not a java method. So I claim it is more accurate to name it as a noun (actor), not a verb. Hence I would name those example lambdas: `lessThanOneTester` and `concatenator`.    

I take the point that it's not always necessary to name trivial lambdas like these, but it can make their intention clearer, and I certainly like to extract any multi-line lambda into a (self-documenting) variable in order to minimise the cognitive load for "future me" staring at it and scratching his head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no specific naming conventions for functional interfaces. Just name them according to what they do:

```
Predicate<Integer> smallerThanOne = i -> (i < 1); 
BiFunction<String, String, String> concatenate = (x, y) -> x + y;
```